# Animate hidden hyperlink to display:block

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, hyperlink

given a hidden hyperlink (hidden by setting display: inline in a css file), how can I achieve to animate this hyperlink to 'display:block'? Neither show() nor the following code

```
 .animate({
     display: block
 }, {
     duration: 500
 }
```

do work!

Anny suggestions?
Cheers,
cube

Comment: `display: inline` doesn't hide it

Answer (score 4):

you are using animate with a wrong css property.

just go like

```
 $('a.link').fadeIn();
```

[here](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/) you can find all the info you need to get started with jquery effects

Comment: Sorry, you are wrong, the use of the fadeIn() effect results in display:inline, that's not what I wanted to achieve. The visible hyperlink has to have display set to "block"!

Comment: sorry. then use .css({display : 'block'}); as a call back function for your animate

like

$("a.link").fadeIn("slow", function() { $(this).css({'display' : 'block'}) });

Comment: the up arrow next to my comment :)

Comment: I hate when correct answers go unvoted and unaccepted, +1 for clear and correct answer

Answer (score 0):

The animate method needs something that has more than 2 states.  Like another answer suggested, you can use the .fadeIn() / .fadeOut methods.  The other choice is to animate the css opacity value.